# how does sort compare lines?

Tags: command-line, url, sorting

I've always assumed that `sort` without any additional arguments, will sort a file in lexical order.
However today I ran across following test case:

```
sort test2.txt
a/a
a/c
a//c
a/d
```

As you can see the third line has two slashes, so the second slash is in a place where neighboring lines have letters 'c' and 'd' respectively. I doubt that '/' comes between 'c' and 'd' in any code-page, so I guess that the default comparison algorithm is not strictly lexical.

Is there some pre-processing (like removing non-letters?) or special cases (like "a sequence of one or more symbols is equal to any other sequence of symbols"?) for comparing symbols?

I've read `man` page for `sort` but I found no enlightenment there.

I use

```
sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

and I really need to sort millions of URLs for further analysis which assumes lexical ordering - are there any options which I could pass to `sort` to achieve this?

Comment: I've performed the same test on my Windows+Cygiwn sort (GNU coreutils) 8.15 Packaged by Cygwin (8.15-1), and it sorts lexically as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your locale, prefix your sort command with a locale setting that specifies the collation order you desire

```
$ cat test2.txt
a/d
a/a
a/c
a//c

$ sort test2.txt
a/a
a/c
a//c
a/d

$ LANG=C sort test2.txt
a//c
a/a
a/c
a/d
```

`man sort` says

```
   *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the  environment  affects  sort
   order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native
   byte values.
```

GNU [say](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Sort-does-not-sort-in-normal-order_0021)

> Most of the language specific locales have tables that specify the
>   sort behavior to ignore punctuation and to fold case. This is counter
>   intuitive to most long time computer users!

---

## NOTE

If your millions of URLs contain any non-ASCII characters (which would make them actually [IRIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_resource_identifier)) you may get unwanted results using a byte-value sort. You can use [URL-encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) to avoid this issue at the risk of making the URLs hard for humans to read.